# Linear Addition of Forces for an Electromagnet design

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

If I have an electromagnet, designed as below(based off an Inrunner BLDC motor), and want to apply 20N of force to the magnet, would I be correct in saying each protrusion(coil and core pair) only need to provide 2N of force as forces acting in the same direction add?

Forgive the wonky diagram, imagine all the protrusions are of equal dimensions.

[image]

Comment: No, forces ad as vectors.

Comment: Yeah, however, how does that make it wrong?
If they all provide 2N in the same direction, would the vectors add to 20N?

Comment: Yes, but they don't

Comment: What does that mean? Could you give more detail...

Comment: Take two of your magnets opposite each other, there force cancels.

Comment: How would the horizontal component(Fx) of the forces cancel? I agree the vertical components would, but I am only interested in the horizontal components...

Comment: horizontal is vertical to the paper? in what direction is the 2N?

Comment: In the direction of the Force arrow of the bar magnet. The magnet is travelling through the gap where N is on the front cross section. If you look at the side cross section, you can see the direction of travel is through. Not up or down...

Comment: the magnet will travel halfway through the gab, but not with 20N and then be stopped when N pol comes to the other side

Comment: Why not with 20N?

Comment: @trula Is it because the fields are perpendicular?